# Using wand to convert image to pdf fails after a few successful results

Tags: python, pdf, wand

My application works a few times and then errors on every pdf. This is the error I receive:

```
Exception TypeError: TypeError("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()",) in <bound method Image.__del__ of <wand.image.Image: (empty)>> ignored
```

And this is the function I use:

```
def read_pdf(file):
    pre, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    filename = pre + '.png'

    with Image(filename=file, resolution=200) as pdf:
        amount_of_pages = len(pdf.sequence)

        image = Image(
            width=pdf.width,
            height=pdf.height * amount_of_pages
        )

        for i in range(0, amount_of_pages):
            image.composite(
                pdf.sequence[i],
                top=pdf.height * i,
                left=0
            )

        image.compression_quality = 100
        image.save(filename=filename)
        logging.info('Opened and saved pdf to image: \'' + file + '\'.')
        return filename
```

This function will correctly convert pdfs to images but after two or three times it will crash every time and throw that exception. If I restart the python script it works again for a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I created a new image and did not destroy it. This filled up the memory.

I just had to use `with new Image(...) as img` instead of `img = new Image(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

The error is caused by the system running out of resources. Wand calls ImageMagick library; which in turn, passes the decoding work to Ghostscript delegate. Ghostscript is very stable, but does use a lot of resources, and is not happy when run in parallel (*my opinion*).

> Any help?

- Try to architect a solution that allows a clean shutdown between PDF conversions. Like a queue worker, or [subprocess](/questions/tagged/subprocess) script. The smallest resources leak can grow out of hand quickly.
- Avoid invoking `wand.image.Image.sequance`. There's been a few known memory leak issues reported. Although many have been fixed, it seems PDF tasks continue to have issues.

From the code posted, it looks like your just creating a tall image with all pages of a given PDF. I would suggest porting `MagickAppendImages` directly.

```py
import ctypes
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

# Map C-API to python
library.MagickAppendImages.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_bool)
library.MagickAppendImages.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

with Image(filename='source.pdf') as pdf:
    # Reset image stack
    library.MagickResetIterator(pdf.wand)
    # Append all pages into one new image
    new_ptr = library.MagickAppendImages(pdf.wand, True)
    library.MagickWriteImage(new_ptr, b'output.png')
    library.DestroyMagickWand(new_ptr)
```

Comment: Updated example code. Does the `convert source.pdf -append output.png` complete successfully w/o any warnings?

Comment: This worked for me, though just calling `sequence[0].destroy()` worked without calling the underlying ImageMagick library. Have spent the last week trying to debug this.